# Transitive actions and equivalence relations (Berkeley Problems in Mathematics)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-actions

This question is about Problem 6.5.12 in the Berkeley Problems in Mathematics, 3rd edition, which reads as follows:

*Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of the group $S_n$.  Suppose that $G$ is a simple group and that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\{1,...,n\}$ such that $i\sim j$ implies that $\sigma(i)\sim \sigma(j)$ for all $\sigma \in G$.  What can one conclude about relation $\sim$?*

After working through the problem I'm still not quite sure what answer this problem might be looking for (unfortunately the answer is not in the back of my edition).  According to Keith Conrad's posting "Transitive Group Actions", relations such as the above are called $G$-equivalence relations, and they can be classified as follows: fix an index in $\{1,...,n\}$ (let's just say $1$ for definiteness).  Then let $H$ be the stabilizer of $1$.  The $G$-equivalence relations on $\{1,...,n\}$ are in bijective correspondence with intermediate subgroups $H \subset K \subset G$ (Theorem 7.5 in the aforementioned article).

All this sounds nice and reasonable to me - but I don't see how simple groups are relevant in any of this, except to say that if $G$ is abelian and simple then there are no non-trivial such equivalence relations since there are no non-trivial intermediate subgroups.  Is there an answer to the above question that takes into account the "simple" part of the requirement in a natural way?

Comment: $G$ being simple implies that all nontrivial actions are faithful. So if there was a nontrivial $G$-equivalence relation (i.e equivalence classes are neither singletons nor the whole set), then you would get an induced faithful action of $G$ on the set of $G$-equivalence classes, which is a smaller set than the original. I have no idea whether this is the intended answer!

Comment: @DerekHolt this cannot be the answer, or at least should not be. The questions asks what we can conclude about $\sim$. I think the answer is 'nothing'. It need not be a trivial equivalence relation. If the embedding $G\to S_n$ were minimal then you can conclude that $\sim$ is a trivial equivalence relation (all equivalent or singletons). I think a hypothesis might have been missed out.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I expect you are right! I was just trying to think of something nontrivial to say

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I agree with you that a hypothesis might have been missed.  The question I wrote above also matches the wording of the test posted in the archive on the Berkeley math webpage, but that is a "re-Texed" version, so a mistake might've occurred when making that copy.

Comment: What you have seems to be the only possible answer. But: simplicity is related to normality, and there is something we can say about the action of normal subgroups $N$: the set of $N$-orbits is a $G$-stable partition. Perhaps the author had at some point intended for this to be incorporated into an exercise but didn't quite get around to it.

Comment: My guess is that $n$ should be assumed to be minimal such that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. That would enable you to say that the equivalence relation was trivial (i.e. 1 or $n$ equivalence classes).